# Delphi Broadcast receiver doesnt work on some devices

Tags: delphi, android-intent, broadcastreceiver

I am trying to receive barcode data from barcode scanner (integrated barcode scanner) from android hand held devices.

Following code working fine on some devices (I realised it works with the devices without google services on). But doesnt work on others which google services enabled on.

```
 procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
 begin
 var
      Filter: JIntentFilter;
 begin
      FMyListener := TMyReceiver.Create;
      FBroadcastReceiver := TJFMXBroadcastReceiver.JavaClass.init(FMyListener);

      Filter := TJIntentFilter.JavaClass.init;
      Filter.addAction(TJIntent.JavaClass.ACTION_SCREEN_OFF);
      Filter.addAction(TJIntent.JavaClass.ACTION_SCREEN_ON);
      Filter.addAction(TJIntent.JavaClass.ACTION_AIRPLANE_MODE_CHANGED);
      Filter.addAction(StringToJString('android.intent.ACTION_DECODE_DATA'));
      TAndroidHelper.context.getApplicationContext.registerReceiver(FBroadcastReceiver, Filter);
 end;
end;
```

Those following actions does work on all of them.

```
Filter.addAction(TJIntent.JavaClass.ACTION_SCREEN_OFF);
Filter.addAction(TJIntent.JavaClass.ACTION_SCREEN_ON);
Filter.addAction(TJIntent.JavaClass.ACTION_AIRPLANE_MODE_CHANGED);
```

But device spesified one

```
Filter.addAction(StringToJString('android.intent.ACTION_DECODE_DATA'));
```

doesn't work on devices which google services on.

I did add the following in to AndroidManifest.template.xml

```
<intent-filter>
     <action android:name="android.intent.ACTION_DECODE_DATA" /> 
     <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
</intent-filter>
```

Please help if anyone has experienced this before.
Thanks